# Preserve inbound URL structure when using mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create an Apache .htaccess rewrite rule, so that when a URL such such as `http://domain.com/1/2` is hit, that it redirects through to `http://domain.com/?object=1&method=2`, however I want it to handle redirect on the Apache level and keep the original pretty URL `http://domain.com/1/2` in the address bar (e.g. no actual browser redirect) is performed, it's almost as though it's simply mapped.

I remember doing this before - but it was a while ago, and I've forgotten how :(.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)[/](.*)[/]?$ /?object=$1&method=$2
```

The rewrite rule works fine, only problem is that it does a browser redirect to `http://domain.com/?object=1&method=2` which means the "pretty URLs" don't persist.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

**Update;** Cleared cache and rule seems to work fine now :).

Comment: The one should only do an external redirect if there's an `[R]` flag somewhere, otherwise it would do exactly what you want. So: either a later rule on this rewriting scheme, or perhaps script / code on the receiving end, does the external redirect.

Comment: Is it possible that Apache rewrite rule flags might persist until flushed or something? I did at one point tag on the [R] flag, but removed it since.

Comment: If you created this config somewhere else then in an `.htaccess` file, than you need to restart the webserver, that's about it.